# Reading from S3 in EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm having troubles reading csv files stored on my bucket on AWS S3 from EMR.

I have read quite a few posts about it and have done the following to make it works :

- Add an IAM policy allowing read & write access to s3
- Tried to pass the uris in the Argument section of the spark-submit request

I thought querying S3 from EMR on a common account was straight forward (because it works locally after defining a fileSystem and providing aws credentials), but when I run :

```
df = spark.read.option("delimiter", ",").csv("s3://{0}/{1}/*.csv".format(bucket_name, power_prod_key), header = True)
```

Nothing happens, there isn't any exception, the cluster keeps running but nothing would be executed after this line (I also have tried to specify a file instead of "*.csv" but it does the same).

I created the cluster using the aws console but here is the exported cli :

```
aws emr create-cluster 
  --applications Name=Hadoop Name=Hive Name=Pig Name=Hue Name=Spark  
  --ec2-attributes '{"InstanceProfile":"EMR_EC2_DefaultRole","SubnetId":"subnet-3482b47e","EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup":"sg-05c284d83c1307807","EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup":"sg-01cd4e90f09dff3ad"}' 
  --release-label emr-5.21.0 
  --log-uri 's3n://aws-logs-597071303168-us-east-1/elasticmapreduce/' 
  --steps '[{"Args":["spark-submit","--deploy-mode","cluster","--py-files","s3://powercaster-bct/code/func.zip","s3://powercaster-bct/code/PowerProdPrediction.py","s3://powercaster-bct/power-production/*.csv","s3://powercaster-bct/results/rnd-frst-predictions.csv","s3://powercaster-bct/results/rnd-frst-target.csv"],"Type":"CUSTOM_JAR","ActionOnFailure":"TERMINATE_CLUSTER","Jar":"command-runner.jar","Properties":"","Name":"Spark application"}]' 
  --instance-groups '[{"InstanceCount":1,"EbsConfiguration":{"EbsBlockDeviceConfigs":[{"VolumeSpecification":{"SizeInGB":32,"VolumeType":"gp2"},"VolumesPerInstance":1}]},"InstanceGroupType":"MASTER","InstanceType":"m4.large","Name":"Master - 1"}]' 
  --configurations '[{"Classification":"spark-env","Properties":{},"Configurations":[{"Classification":"export","Properties":{"PYSPARK_PYTHON":"/usr/bin/python3"}}]}]' 
  --auto-terminate 
  --auto-scaling-role EMR_AutoScaling_DefaultRole 
  --ebs-root-volume-size 10 
  --service-role EMR_DefaultRole 
  --enable-debugging 
  --name 'My cluster' 
  --scale-down-behavior TERMINATE_AT_TASK_COMPLETION 
  --region us-east-1
```

Should I provide some specific hadoop configuration to define a fileSystem or give my credentials somehow ?

Any idea why I can't link S3 to EMR ?

Comment: Can u plz share your emr logs

Comment: When using interactive shell and read some files (text/parquet/anything), does it complain?

Comment: @vaquarkhan which logs ? The console provides plenty of different log categories : containers/, nodes/, steps/

Comment: @Bala I have never used interactive shell, I'm just deploying a cluster in step execution mode to do some test. I don't know how it works

Comment: I recommend that you logon to (ssh) Master node, run the interactive shell, execute your commands and see if it throws any errors.  Do you get any errors at all?

Comment: Analysis on all logs and try to find what error are you getting ,will share with your question to get quick and proper answer ,since we have no visibility on your EMR cluster depends on info u will add here to help u

Comment: If I submit my job using the interactive shell and use the spark-submit command, I am able to read a file (the "*.csv" failed though), any reason it doesn't work when I execute it from the AWS console ? Thanks

Comment: Before you run your spark shell run a baseline 
aws s3 ls

Do you see your buckets if so run the before series of commands entering the name of bucket and folder path
val bucketName = ""
val folderPath = ""
val inputDF = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("delimiter","true").load("s3://" + bucketName + "/" + folderPath + "/") 

This is to check if the issue is with the formatting of the folder path or not.

If both above do not work run
aws config and change the region argument to the region where your buckets and account exists.