# Problems reading from EMR cluster in S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am developing an application on Java Spark. Generated and successfully loaded the `.jar` to the EMR cluster. There is one line of the code that reads:

```
JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("s3://naturgy-sabt-dev/QUERY/input.json"));
```

I am 100% sure of:

- Such file does exist.
- When executing `aws s3 cp s3://naturgy-sabt-dev/QUERY/input.json .` I'm receiving correctly the `.json` file.
- IAM policies are set so that the tied EMR role has permissions to read, write and list.
- [This post about how to read from S3 in EMR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55239088/reading-from-s3-in-emr) does not help.

When submitting the spark `jar`, I am getting the following error:
(Note the printing of the route that it is going to be read right before calling the Java statement above put)

```
...
...
...
19/12/11 15:55:46 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 172.31.36.11, 35744, None)
19/12/11 15:55:46 INFO BlockManager: external shuffle service port = 7337
19/12/11 15:55:46 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 172.31.36.11, 35744, None)
19/12/11 15:55:48 INFO EventLoggingListener: Logging events to hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps/local-1576079746613
19/12/11 15:55:48 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'hdfs:///user/spark/warehouse'.
#########################################
I am going to read from s3://naturgy-sabt-dev/QUERY/input.json
#########################################
java.io.FileNotFoundException: s3:/naturgy-sabt-dev/QUERY/input.json (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
...
...
...
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Did you open your `.jar` to check the exact path of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java default Filereader cannot load files from aws s3 by.
They can only be read with 3d party libs. The bare s3 reader is shipped within java aws sdk.
However hadoop has also libraries to read from s3. Hadoop jars are preinstalled on aws emr spark cluster (actually on almost all spark installs).

Spark supports loading data from s3 filesystem into a spark dataframe directly without any manual steps. All readers can read either one file, or multiple files with same structure via a glob pattern. The [json dataframe](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#json-java.lang.String-) reader expects [new-line delimited json](http://jsonlines.org/) by default. This can be configured.

various usage ways

```
# read single new-line delimited json file, each line is a record
spark.read.json("s3://path/input.json")

# read single serilized json object or array, spanning multiple lines.
spark.read.option("multiLine", true).json("s3://path/input.json")

# read multiple json files 
spark.read.json("s3://folder/*.json")
```